# python: why doesn't this write to file on new line?

Tags: python, file, python-3.x

```
def log():
    with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
        print ".log.txt"
        f.write(msg.encode('utf-8') +"\n")
```

I call log() several times but doesn't write each msg on new line, and I have no clue why. I tried adding f.close() at the end but that didn't work either. Super frustrating!

Comment: If you want to have logging in your own application, please use extensively tested and used facilities: https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you wanted to define `log()` as `log(msg)` :). I tried it and it worked on my system (OS X). `\n` should work, but it's not 100% cross platform so try using `os.linesep` instead.

```
# test.py
import os

def log(msg):
    with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
        f.write(msg.encode('utf-8') + os.linesep)

log('aaa')
log('bbb')
```

Then:

```
$ python test.py 
$ cat log.txt 
aaa
bbb
```

Answer (score -1):

You didn't given the msg.

```
def log():
    msg="bhansa"
    with open("log.txt", 'a') as f:
        print ".log.txt"
        f.write(msg.encode('utf-8') +"\n")
log()
```

or pass the msg in your method.

It's Working Fine.

Comment: `msg.encode('utf-8') +"\n"` does not work with Python 3; strings do not concatenate to bytes.